# Why OnOptionsMenuClosed not called on Android

Tags: android

It is necessary to hide the ActionBar after you exit the menu. To trap closing Overriding onOptionsMenuClosed (Menu menu) in the Activity. But the menu is closed, this method is not invoked. And not when I click "back" or when touch by the menu. How to fix it?

This is my code in Main.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_fomenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.default_lista_betoltese) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Alaplista betöltése kész",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.lista_betoltese) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Mentett lista betöltése kész",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.lista_mentese) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Mentés kész",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.szerkeszto_mod) {
        szerkeszto_mod(!szerkesztomod);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.betumeret_noveles) {
        betumeret++;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Betűméret: " + betumeret,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed (Menu menu) {
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

Comment: I see nothing in the Android source code to suggest that `onOptionsMenuClosed()` is used by action bar implementations. Bear in mind that the real "options menu" is only used if you try defining a menu and have no action bar, and it dates back to Android 1.x/2.x.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand, thank you! I tried to use this for the action bar's menu handling. How can i catch the action bar's menu close?

Comment: If by "menu", you mean the overflow, I do not recall there being an event for that, though I have not looked for one and may simply be forgetting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener for receiving events when action bar menus are shown or hidden.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener.html